# Lua KSP placing samples in groups

Tags: lua, group, kontakt.io

I have little C++ programming knowledge, I just have used MATLAB for my jobs.
Anyway I want to modify a Kontakt script via Lua and I can't understand by reading manual and tutorials how to do it.
I saw some scripts in which they load the samples and then assign them by zones, pitches or similar but thats not what I need.
I just have to put one sample per group with that group named as the sample (it's how the original script is made).
I don't understand how to loop through the loaded samples (are they loaded as arrays? Tables?), just get the name of each sample and use it to name the group, put all of them on the same key and thats it.
In MATLAB i would have done it something like that

```matlab
For i=1: lenght(samples)
Name(i)=getsamplename(i)
End
```

And then put the samples in there.
Any help?

Tried to modify one of the tutorials to just make all the samples on one note but it didn't work.